# Как оптимизировать анимацию?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, css-animation

На смартфоне при использовании такой анимции проседают кадры.
Как оптимизировать такую анимацию?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  position: relative;
}

.box p {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  transition: margin-bottom .5s;
}

.box-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://wemodern.xyz/images/photo_2019-09-28_22-31-17.jpg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height .5s;
}

.nav-deploy {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-deploy-check {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav-deploy-check:checked~.box-image {
  height: 600px;
  transition: height .5s;
}

#nav-deploy-check:checked~p {
  margin-bottom: 600px;
  transition: margin-bottom .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-deploy-check">
    <div class="nav-deploy">Развернуть</div>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur similique quod omnis
    </p>
    <div class="box-image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Купить смартфон помощнее.

Comment: наверное анимация scale поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас этот блок не висит сферически в вакууме, а плавно сдвигает вниз какой-либо контент, то кадры могут проседать даже после хорошей оптимизации. Происходить это будет из-за того, что каждый кадр будет вызывать Relayout в конвейере пикселей, а это дорогая процедура. Что можно сделать по вашей анимации конкретно - как минимум переверстать так, чтобы убрать `transition: margin-bottom .5s`, поскольку это одно из самых дорогих для анимации свойств. Советы выше тоже *в целом* хорошие, я бы лишь добавил, что стоит стремиться к тому, чтобы иметь возможность анимировать только свойства `transform` и `opacity`.

Comment: А если при анимации блок не будет двигать "соседей", а висеть, допустим в `position: absolute`, или иметь фиксированную высоту родителя, при этому уходить за его границы.. Это сэкономит ресурс?

Comment: Если увеличение не будет влиять на другой контент, то все будет намного лучше. Посмотрите как на пример https://csstriggers.com/ - можно заметить, как внизу зарезервировано место под раскрытие блоков и что все блоки после раскрытия одного из них смещаются вниз при помощи `transform`.

Comment: @Sasha А если сверстать эту анимацию используя requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` не панацея, это, условно говоря, приглашение делать отрисовку в свободное от вычислений время. Поэкспериментировать стоит, конечно.

Answer (score 3):

Определенная часть анимации на телефоне не возможно довести до нормального состояния, не обращая внимания на их простоту. Однако следующие советы могут помочь:

1. Используйте `transform`, где возможно, а желательно с 3d, даже если Вам не нужен 3d. Например, для передвижение элементов используйте `translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);`.
2. Используйте вместо opacity => filter: opacity()
3. Делайте специальные изображения для мобильных телефонов. Оптимизируйте их максимально.
4. Добавьте `will-change: transform;` там где будите использовать `transform`.
5. Отключение `pointer-events`, где это возможно, может положительный результат

Comment: Интересно, а есть ли где-то информация об этих решениях для оптимизации?

Answer (score 2):

1. Купить смартфон помощнее.
2. Не насиловать несчастный недобраузер смартфона громоздкими пересчетами больших картинок.
3. Попробовать анимировать не саму картинку, а некий элемент, например, `<div>`, которому задавать нужные размеры, а картинку задать ему в качестве фона, проставив нужные значения свойства `background-size`, например, `100% auto`.

---

4. Трансформировать весь блок с помошью `transform:scale(...)`. Только нужно учесть, что место, выделенное под этот блок до трансформации, не изменится, а значит, придется сдвигать соседние элементы с помошью либо трансформации их свойств, либо изменением габаритов какого-нибудь родительского контейнера.

Примерно так:

```
.parent_container {
  height:600px;
  ...
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.image_container {
  height:600px;
  ...
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.parent_container.transformed {
  height:200px;
}

.parent_container.transformed .image_container {
  transform:scale(calc 600px / 200px);
  ...
}
```

Comment: У меня так и реализовано

Comment: А, точно, пардон. Дополнил ответ.